# Searching for geometric shape on cartesian plane by coordinates

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry

I have an algorithmic problem on a Cartesian plane.. I need to efficiently search for geometric shapes that intersect with a given point. There are several shapes(rectangle, circle, triangle and polygon) but those are not important, because the determining the actual point inclusion is not a problem here, I will implement those on my own. The problem lies in determining which shapes need to be verified for the inclusion with the given point. Iterating through all of my shapes on plane and running the point inclusion method on each one of them is inefficient as the number of instances of shapes will be quite large. My first idea was to divide the plane for segments(the plane is finite, but too large for any kind of 3D array) and when adding a shape to the database, i would determine which segments it would intersect with and save them within object of the shape. Then when the point for inclusion verification is given, I would only need to determine the segment in which the point is located and then verify the inclusion only with objects which intersect with that segment.

Is that the way to go? I don't know if the method I described is optimal or if i am not missing something. Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance

P.S.: I will be writing this in C++. That is not really relevant as it is more of an algorithmic problem but I wanted to put that out if someone was curious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gridding approach can be used here.

See the plane as a raster image where you draw all your shapes using a scan conversion algorithm, making sure that all pixels even partially covered are filled. For every image pixel, keep a list of the shapes that filled it.

A query is then straightforward: find the pixel where the query point falls in time `O(1)` and check every shape in the list, in time `O(K)`, where `K` is the list length, approximately equal to the number of intersecting shapes.

If your image is made of `N²` pixels and you have `M` objects having an average area `A` pixels, you will need to store `N²+M.A` list elements (a shape identifier + a link to the next). You will choose the pixel size to achieve a good compromise between accuracy and storage cost. In any case, you must limit yourself to `N²<Q.M`, where `Q` is the total number of queries, otherwise the cost of just initializing the image could exceed the total query time.

In case your scene is very sparse (more voids than shapes), you can use a compressed representation of the image, using a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).